# Can we Embed an Image to a Email without using HTML?

Tags: c#, html, email, inline-images

I want to send an e-mail consisting an image from my C# program. I can completely do that using the code samples at [How to Send Mails from your GMAIL Account through VB.NET or C#. Windows Programming, with a Bit of Customization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Sending_Emails_From_GMAIL.aspx?msg=3993090#xx3993090xx)

But when I used another email service, they just remove the HTML tagged part including the image from the email! So does anyone know a method to embed the image without using HTML tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the entire html being removed or are the images just being blocked from being displayed? Some people will prevent you from seeing external images, in this case it's possible to embed and display the embedded image.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can send it as an attachment?
Can that be an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any way to do that other than the old:

- send as attachment
- just paste the full (or shortened) link into your content body